# Website not scrolling on an android mobile

Tags: android, css, web, scroll

I'm working on a website that scrolls as it should in Desktop and iPhone, but it doesn't scrolls in Android mobile (testing on Huawei P10).

In my css I have lines like:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  min-height:100%; height:100%; 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  background: url('../img/bg-main.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you wanted to see, this is the website: [CLICK](http://urszulagolaszewska.pl/)

Comment: Try adding a property
`overflow: auto;` to your CSS

Comment: @Frost still no scrolling on android

Comment: Does your first html line change the class: `<html lang="en" class="{proper device class}">` depending on the device?

Comment: @Mr.Drew no, it starts a bit differently. As I am not a web developer (webpage comes from a template), I don't understand all the instructions: [here](https://i.imgur.com/tGuF7YJ.png)

Comment: ah i see, well then you should probably contact the seller of the template then? Or look for others with the same issues. I'm not sure what is the problem is exactly, but it does scroll on mobile (not the white space, but try scrolling via the side/background and you'll find it works). This is probably something to do with how the js is being rendered to the foreground which isn't scrollable on android, even though the background/main view is..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that its this "perfect scrollbar" that the website is using. It appears even on my chrome desktop, and is displayed alongside the regular scrollbar. I'd remove it entirely and I'd expect the website to scroll correctly.   `<!-- Perfect ScrollBar -->
<link href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @MattfromVisionApp No, it actually didn't help. Still same behaviour on android phone